# Search and replace C# expression

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio, roslyn

Time and again I find myself needing to change the use of one method call with another.

E.g. I have 100 occurrences of method calls similar to this:

```
Helper.GetIntFromData(packetData.Skip(offset).Take(length).ToArray());
```

that need to be changed to

```
Helper.GetIntFromData(packetData, offset, length);
```

This is relatively easily solved with a regular expression. But what if **whitespace** (sometimes) comes into play ?

```
Helper.GetIntFromData(packetData
    .Skip(  offset  )
    .Take(  length  )
    .ToArray()  
);
```

Still doable with a regex, but it's now an unreadable mess of optional whitespace tokens.

OK, but what if the *parameters* are not always simple identifiers, but **arbitrary expressions**?

```
Helper.GetIntFromData(obj.GetData(true).Skip( 7 + GetOffset( item.GetData() ) )
    .Take( length1 / length2 ).ToArray());
```

This is where regular expressions really break down.

#### My question is:

Can this be done today? (in a way that keeps you sane, i.e. without regex)

Is there a VS extension or standalone tool that can handle searching and replacing C# code at a higher (semantic) level?

Something that would allow me to search for (I imagine):

```
Helper.GetIntFromData($expr1.Skip($expr2).Take($expr3).ToArray())
```

and replace with

```
Helper.GetIntFromData($1, $2, $3)
```

Does such a tool exist for C#? (I imagine it could be built around Roslyn.)

Answer (score 1):

Resharper has semantic search and replace

```
Helper.GetIntFromData(packetData.Skip($offset$).Take($length$).ToArray());
```

with

```
Helper.GetIntFromData(packetData, $offset$, $length$);
```

It is white space insensitive and you can constrain the token matches to be of certain types. I use it all the time to do what you are trying to do. I have not yet seen any roslyn based projects that all the user to do this so trivially.

Here is an intro to the feature on resharpers website

http://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2010/04/07/introducing-resharper-50-structural-search-and-replace/

Comment: Man, I could never get that to work. Guess it's time to give it another try.

Answer (score 0):

After giving it another thought, what you're trying to achieve is dangerous and better be avoided. A RegEx match / replace is a limited feature. It can not "understand" complex code, and is bound to fail. Consider an example like (lets ignore for a second if that code even makes sense):

`Helper.GetIntFromData(packetData.Skip(skipArray.Take(1)).Take(length).ToArray());`

A regular expression that's not specifically tailored to avoid the "wrong `Take`" doesn't stand a chance. It is a matter of time until your auto-replacing method breaks your code, and your only hope is that it's brutal enough to generate a compile time error. It might just as well create tough to find runtime exception or worse, unexplained behavior. Code refactoring should be done with a tool that understands code, not a tool that recognizes text patterns.

Comment: Exactly. That's why I am asking about semantic search/replace -- not syntactic, like regex.

Answer (score 0):

If at all possible, I'd do it "manually", but using simple regexes (yes, I know you said without them, and Amit's answer "looks right" though I've not checked it for edge cases).

Something like this:

```
Helper.GetIntFromData(packetData.Skip(offset).Take(length).ToArray());
Helper.GetIntFromData(obj.GetData(true).Skip( 7 + GetOffset( item.GetData() ) )
    .Take( length1 / length2 ).ToArray());
```

Replace `(Helper.GetIntFromData.*?)\.Skip\(` with `\1,` to get

```
Helper.GetIntFromData(packetData, offset).Take(length).ToArray());
Helper.GetIntFromData(obj.GetData(true),  7 + GetOffset( item.GetData() ) )
    .Take( length1 / length2 ).ToArray());
```

Then replace `(Helper.GetIntFromData.*?)\)\.Take\(` with `\1,` to get

```
Helper.GetIntFromData(packetData, offset, length).ToArray());
Helper.GetIntFromData(obj.GetData(true),  7 + GetOffset( item.GetData() ) 
    ,  length1 / length2 ).ToArray());
```

And finally replace `(Helper.GetIntFromData.*?)\)\.ToArray\(\)\);` with `\1\);` to get

```
Helper.GetIntFromData(packetData, offset, length);
Helper.GetIntFromData(obj.GetData(true),  7 + GetOffset( item.GetData() ) 
    ,  length1 / length2 );
```